# Pyperclip error in Pythonista on iPad Pro

Tags: python-3.x, pyperclip

I am learning Python 3 using a Udemy course. One of the course modules asks us to install Pyperclip in order to try out simple code is the console.

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy(‘Test’)
pyperclip.paste()
```

I believe this should output the word Test in the console.

I did the following:

1. Installed Stash
2. Installed Pyperclip by running the command ‘pip install Pyperclip’ from within Stash. Package installed fine
3. Went back to console and ran the import Pyperclip command. No errors

However, when I try to run the function Pyperclip.copy() or .paste() I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C6F5AC74-E13C-4A33-95BA-F075B9E680F9/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 120, in copy_osx_pbcopy
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/479FB713-67AD-4A41-9180-71A1C27C61E8/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 708, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/479FB713-67AD-4A41-9180-71A1C27C61E8/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 1261, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I looked around for similar errors on stack overflow but the issues/ answers don’t seem to fit my situation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pyperclip is not supported by Pythonista. Try their built in module, clipboard.  http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/clipboard.html